# get Metadata Error while using video in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

I tried to import the video in 2 ways one by including the video file into Raw folder and other is directly calling the link

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class HomeVideo extends Activity{
    private VideoView videoView;
    String extStorageDirectory;
    private String current;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set the view to our layout file
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Video view: to view our video
        String path ="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
        VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://comm.fib.work/"+R.raw.test2);

    //Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
    }
```

}

In Error Log it shows

05-15 13:54:14.981: D/MediaPlayer(586): getMetadata
05-15 13:57:57.711: D/MediaPlayer(623): getMetadata

I included the permission in manifest

```
    </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

I cant find what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

hey did you tried to use this path for raw files?

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourproject/raw/videofile")
```

that worked 100% for me
hope it helps :